# Replacing table row dynamically using jquery

Tags: jquery

Below is the jQuery code which creates table with some rows dynamically when ajax request is success.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#rule_search_submit").click(function () {
        var search_rule_name = $("#search_rule_name").val();
        //alert(search_rule_name);
        $.ajax({
            url: "searchrule",
            type: "POST",
            data: "search_rule_name=" + search_rule_name,
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (k, item) {
                    $("#search_rule_table").after('<tr id="table_row_id"><td><input type="radio" name="rule_radio" id="rule_radio"    value="' + item.rule_name + ',' + item.rule_desc + ',' + item.start_date + ',' + item.end_date + ',' + item.rule_id + ',' + item.status + '"/></td><td>' + item.rule_name + '</td></tr>');
                });
            },
            error: showCustError
        });
    });
});
```

it creates two rows with radio button and title.
Below is the code to access values from database when radio button is clicked

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name='rule_radio']").live("change", function () {
        var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
        var id_name = parent.attr("id");
        var rule_data = $(this).val().split(",");
        document.getElementById("edit_rule_name").value = rule_data[0];
        document.getElementById("edit_rule_desc").value = rule_data[1];
        document.getElementById("edit_start_date").value = rule_data[2];
        document.getElementById("edit_end_date").value = rule_data[3];
        document.getElementById("edit_ruleid").value = rule_data[4];
    });
});
```

Below is the code to replace the dynamically created table row on some ajax response

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#save_rule").click(function () {
        var ruleid = document.getElementById("edit_ruleid").value;
        var rulename = document.getElementById("edit_rule_name").value;
        var ruledesc = document.getElementById("edit_rule_desc").value;
        var start_date = document.getElementById("edit_start_date").value;
        var end_date = document.getElementById("edit_end_date").value;
        var type = "editrule";
        if (ruleid == "")
            alert('Please select the rule to edit');
        else {
            $.ajax({
                url: "addrule",
                type: "GET",
                data: "ruleid=" + ruleid + "&rulename=" + rulename + "&ruledesc=" + ruledesc + "&start_date=" + start_date + "&end_date=" + end_date + "&type=" + type,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#table_row_id").replaceWith('<tr id="table_row_id"><td><input type="radio"   name="rule_radio" id="rule_radio"     value="' + data[0].rule_name + ',' + data[0].rule_desc + ',' + data[0].start_date + ',' + data[0].end_dat e + ',' + data[0].rule_id + ',' + data[0].status + '"/></td><td>' + data[0].rule_name + '</td>        </tr>');
                },
                error: showCustError
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Unfortunately I am unable to replace the rows dynamically on ajax response. Please suggest me to resolve this task.

Comment: 1. live is removed as of jQuery 1.9. 2. use event delegation. 3. use unique ID's.

Comment: Your problem is that your are not using unique `id`s

Comment: please replace document.getElementById(" <-- with --> $("#

Comment: Please suggest me how to add uniqe id's and how to access those unique id's while creating dynamic table rows.